# Revert mmenu back to the panel with the selected item when closed

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I've been tooling around with the jquery mmenu plugin found here [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl).

The menu will render to the correct sub-panel as long as you add class="Selected" to the appropriate LI tag. I'm looking for a way for it to revert back to this panel upon closing if the user happened to navigate to sub-menus without ultimately making a selection. Thus, the next time you open the menu, it's set to the panel that was originally opened when the page loaded.

If you use this [demo](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/demo/index.html?demo=default), open the menu, click the arrow to get to the **About us** sub-menu, click the arrow to get to the **The team** sub-menu, don't make a selection and click the hamburger icon to close the menu. Upon opening the menu again, you're on the **The team** menu rather than the menu that was displayed when the page first loaded. I know how to revert the menu back to the top level menu on closing using closeAllPanels(), but I can't figure out how to get it back to the panel with the original selected LI.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this can be accomplished with the following:

```
menu.bind( "closed", function() {
    menu.openPanel($('li.mm-selected').closest('.mm-panel'));
});
```